# Offline use of semantic web vocabularies

Tags: offline, semantic-web, vocabulary, foaf

There are some useful vocabularies out there for use of semantic web applications, one of which is the well known "foaf".
How should I use it in an offline system, meaning a network disconnected from the www?
Is it downloadable? Should I use some DNS "trickery" in my network? Is it at all possible?

Comment: http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/index.rdf. Perhaps you are talking about _URI dereferencing_, but probably you don't need it. Also, try Protégé import capabilities.

Comment: @StanislavKralin, I went and read about Protégé import. It is described how an import statement is written to the importing ontology, but I didn't understand if it is also kept localy, or every time the ontology is loaded, Protégé accesses the location on the web.

Comment: AFAIK, Protege uses [XML Catalog](https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/How_Owl_2.0_Imports_Work#Generating_XML_Catalogs_During_download). Just experiment with it and see what happens.

Comment: It really depends on what technology/software you are using, but yes, you can download ontologies and use them offline. You only need to go online to get some data that is not in your store, but as an example, running a SPARQL query over local data won't actually hit the URI's mentioned, such as foaf:knows to check them, it just assumes they'll be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the comments above and some more reading I had, the solution seems to be downloading the necessary ontologies and saving them to the cache of whichever tool you're using.
Whenever an ontology is needed, the cache will be checked first, so no access to the network will be made.